# What is an efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column in dataframes which contains values `'a','b','c','d' and 'e'` and there total **1.5 million** records. I would like to convert the values in to numerical categories such as 
`a=>1,b=>2,c=>3,d=>4 and e=>5`.

Since I have **1.5 million** records, what is the most *efficient* way I can do this operation?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? This kind of operation is **well documented**: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have tried itertuples,iteritems....both taking a lot of time.

Comment: There are no efficient ways of looping when it comes to DataFrames. The efficient ways are vectorized but you'll have to define your problem more clearly (with a sample input and desired output pair) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @ayhan if have a column in my dataframe having values a to e. I want to conert them to numbers such as a to 1, b to 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `df.applymap()` with an efficient function would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())[0].reshape(len(df), -1) + 1,
    df.index, df.columns
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16188660)

Comment: @DonaldDuck thx for the feedback. I'll improve it when I can.